# Android touchevent on view even with dialog in front

Tags: java, android

I am making video playback controls.  All my code is present to make it work and it does, except for one thing.  When I touch the surfaceview the controls come up, but once they are up, my surfaceview no longer has focused and doesn't receive touch events.  What I need is for the surface view to still get touch events even with the dialog open.  Also my dialog must also be able to receive touch events.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another View in the same layout that sits layered on top of your SurfaceView for controls rather than a Dialog. Dialogs are meant for modal interactions - they are intended to block you from interacting with whatever is underneath.

Comment: There is no way of catching those touch events with a dialog open? We have a lot of code tied around this dialog, it would be a lot of work to refactor.

Comment: You might try adding the window flag FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL to your dialog's window, but you're really using the wrong tool for the job here. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL